# What is wrong with this AES encryption/decryption?

Tags: java, encryption, base64, aes

We get this random error when decrypting an encrypted string. If we try to decrypt the second time, it works

```
String salt = "This is my test";
byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] ivBytes = new byte[] { (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C, 0x07,
    0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A, (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C, 0x07, 0x72,
    0x6F, 0x5A };
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
    .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(encryptionKey.toCharArray(), saltBytes,
    iterationCount, keySize);

SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
```

### Encryption code:

```
byte[] encryptedTextBytes=encryptionCipher.doFinal(stringToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF- 8"));
encrypted = new Base64().encodeAsString(encryptedTextBytes);
```

### Decryption code:

```
byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new Base64().decodeBase64(encryptedText);
decryptedTextBytes = decryptionCipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);
return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
```

The issue occurs randomly.

Comment: You forgot to include the error. Please add the stack trace to your question. Please also convert your code to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that we can reproduce it ourselves.

Comment: This occured in our live environment and we didn't catch the exceptions. This occurs randomly and so I haven't been able to replicate it. But I have experienced it and so have have some of our users

Comment: You don't store exceptions that occur in your live environment? Eeek - something to fix in your next release. In the meantime, can you at least show us how you create your key factory and how your `ivBytes` variable is generated.

Comment: Thanks for getting some more code. But please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20967518/edit) rather than posting chunks of code in a comment.

Comment: I have added the code to catch the exception in production. Now I have to wait for the issue to reoccur. Do you see anything wrong with the code

Comment: With the exception of not knowing where `encryptionKey` comes from, the rest looks pretty standard.